# How to define a AppicationUser in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to get current user details in asp.net core. I saw this tutorial

https://adrientorris.github.io/aspnet-core/identity/how-to-get-current-logged-in-user-id.html

but they use a `ApplicationUser`, but no where can I find out what it is and how to define it. Does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: It's just a class that inherits from the Identity user class, `IdentityUser`.  You should already have one in your app if you used the default template.

Comment: I did use the default template, but I don't see it anywhere

Comment: Look harder then, it's definitely in there...

Comment: can't find it..

Comment: Look in your `startup.cs` file, is it mentioned in there? If so, click on it and press F12.

Comment: It is not defined in there.

Comment: Do you have a line that says `services.AddIdentity`?

Comment: i do not. It only had `services.AddMvc();`

Comment: So you don't have any Identity code in your project at all?

Comment: i think that is the case

Comment: How do I start a project with all that already in?

Comment: Create a new project and when it asks you if you want authentication, say yes!

Comment: I did that after with a test project and it was the same thing.

Comment: Then you will have an `ApplicationUser` class.